# understanding the expression (value, otherValue)

Tags: javascript

I found this in a javascript test.
How come `(1,4)` returns `4` ?

what is going on in that expression ?

Would someone have a link to the doc concerning it ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: (Google "Javascript comma operator" and you get the answer...)